# Usage of 'ведь'

Tags: словоупотребление, значения

I wish I could find a more directly way to phrase this question, but as an English speaker learning Russian, I rarely use the word 'ведь'. I am interested in two things from native speakers: 1) In your view, is 'ведь' necessary to use in order to express some thoughts/types of sentences (examples are very welcome), 2) If so, how do I incorporate it more into my speech? How would you recommend conceptualizing it?

Answer (score 3):

Typically, *ведь* is a part of a phrase explaining the reason for something, most often it's a reminder that the reason is known (or easily understandable) to those addressed. It sounds like '*as you know*', '*as we both know*', '*as everybody knows*','*as I already knew*' , '*since*', etc.

```
Мыть посуду придётся тебе, ведь это ты оставил тарелки после еды.
```

(It's your turn to wash the dishes since it was you who left those plates on the table after dinner.)

```
Я поспешил скрыться, ведь он собирался меня убить.
```

(I made a quick escape: I knew he was going to kill me.)

**P.S.** Where to use or not to use it. As with the equivalent expressions above: in official documents, something like *потому что* (because) should be used instead. In case of a dialogue or some interactive writing *ведь* implies the listener or reader would definitely agree with what is said or written just after that word.

Answer (score 2):

By using *ведь* in a question, you make it sound confirming something you already know (*ведь* is etymologically related to "I know"):

> Это ты разбил чашку? // Was it you who broke the cup? (I'm genuinely interested)
>
> Ведь это ты разбил чашку? // It was you who broke the cup, wasn't it? (I'd be surprised if it wasn't you)