# Interpretation of the particle "ведь"

Tags: particles

In this passage, in response to a story about candies that contained Radium, does ведь have the force of "you see, I tried..." or does it justify the previous statement (exclamation) like a sort of "I say this because I tried..." or does it imply something else entirely that I'm missing?

> Уххх, ну и история :) Я **ведь** пробовал такие в детстве. Они здесь
>   считались большой редкостью в 90-ых годах.

Comment: for one thing, `пробовать` in this case means `to taste` not `to try`

Comment: or at least "to have previous (little) experience in eating of some food"

Comment: in my opinion `ведь` here adds something like an exclamation. The idea is to say, that `look, this thing is dangerous, but I have eaten it before !!!`. So the speaker is impressed himself about this fact

Comment: Sorry for the first comment, I just looked into the dictionary, and found that `to try` in English has exactly the same meaning as Russian "пробовать, отведывать (еду)"

Comment: I think it's akin to now obsolete "for sooth" English expression or nowadays rare "indeed", i.e. "I **indeed** had tasted those in my childhood."

Comment: @user907860: For another thing, in English, try also means taste.

Comment: Almost identical question from last month: http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/10596/usage-of-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the most precise translation for this case is "actually":

```
I've actually tried those in my childhood.
```

Comment: Nice! That is actually very helpful :)

Answer (score 3):

Большой толковой словарь (Кузнецов) says:

```
1. *частица.* для усиления основного содержания всего высказывания
(предположения, утверждения, вопроса и т.п.) или выделения, подчёркивания отдельного слова.

2.*союз.*
 1) Присоединяет предложения, содержащие указание на причину, обоснование 
предыдущего высказывания. 
"Полагаемся на тебя, ты ведь один знаешь дорогу."
"Пора домой, ведь уже поздно."

2) Несмотря на то, что; хотя. 
"Ведь и сил нет, а работаешь." 
"Ведь говорил вам, да не послушались."
```

And Большой современный толковый словарь русского языка (Ефремова) says:

```
I 1. Употребляется при присоединении предложения, в котором указывается причина или 
обоснование предыдущего высказывания. 2. Употребляется при выражении уступительности, 
соответствуя по значению сл.: хотя, несмотря на то что. 3. Употребляется при выражении 
предположительного или возможного условия. II Употребляется при подчеркивании чего-либо 
сказанного или при противопоставлении сказанного чему-либо другому.
```

It's usually translated as "after all" or often just omitted.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/754910) is this word in the dictionary.
This case is described in

> 5. В разг. речи придает эмоциональную окраску высказыванию.

­- In colloquial speech adds an emotional expressiveness.
(It does not add any information.)